# Difference between factor and character variables running randomForest

Tags: r, random-forest

If I run a `randomForest(y ~ x, data = df)` model, `x` a factor variable with more than 53 levels I get

```
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 53 categories.
```

If I change `x` to `as.character(x)` and re-run I get no errors.

What's the difference behind the scenes? Isn't both types treated as categorical variables?

Comment: They should both be treated as categorical variables. I'm honestly not sure but you may try fitting a RF with predictors having less than 53 categories and see whether it provides the same results when they're treated as factors and as characters. However, IMO you should avoid exploiting this RF function for predictors with more than 53 categories because, even if treating the predictor as a character works, the fact that treating it as a factor doesn't work may be an indication of a possibly bad behavior of the model in this circumstance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess each category's name is a numeric value (because `randomForest()` can't treat `character class` when it consist of character). `randomForest()` treat `character class` which consist of numeric value as numeric variables (i.e., `numeric class`), NOT categorical variables (i.e., `factor class`). If you change each category's name, the result will change.

Here is my example. If x_ is `factor class`, the same results return. If x_ is `integer class` or `character class (but composed of numeric value)`, the outputs depend on the value. The result you got by `as.character(x)` is CLEARY WRONG !!

```
set.seed(1); cw <- data.frame(y = subset(ChickWeight, Time==18)$weight, x1 = sample(47) )
cw$x2 <- as.factor(cw$x1)
cw$x3 <- as.character(cw$x1)
cw$x4 <- 47:1
cw$x5 <- as.factor(47:1)
cw$x6 <- as.character(47:1)
cw$x7 <- c(letters, LETTERS[1:21])
cw$x8 <- as.factor(cw$x7)
                               # %Var explained # class(x_)
set.seed(1); randomForest(y ~ x1, cw) # -29.61  integer1
set.seed(1); randomForest(y ~ x2, cw) # -0.42   factor
set.seed(1); randomForest(y ~ x3, cw) # -29.61  character (numeric name1)
set.seed(1); randomForest(y ~ x4, cw) # -31.78  integer2
set.seed(1); randomForest(y ~ x5, cw) # -0.42   factor
set.seed(1); randomForest(y ~ x6, cw) # -31.78  character (numeric name2)
set.seed(1); randomForest(y ~ x7, cw) # error   character (letter name)
set.seed(1); randomForest(y ~ x8, cw) # -0.42   factor
```

Comment: Great practical example! I need to check the code but probably what it's doing is applying a `as.numeric` to every `character` variable. If it can't be converted to numeric it returns NAs and then the function throws an error. `as.numeric("1234") -> no errors` and  `as.numeric("abcd") -> NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: I’m glad you like it. (and I edited my poot English a little)